# What are the order of operations in this recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Recursion in javascript is eluding me.  I'm almost there, but I'm a bit confused about the order of operations.  Take for example the following function:

```
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (endNum - startNum === 0) {
    return [startNum];
  } else {
    var numbers = rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum - 1);
    numbers.push(endNum);
    return numbers;
  }
}
```

Questions I'm trying to figure out:

1. Does this create a closure around `numbers`?
2. Does the function `rangeOfNumbers` return `numbers` every single time, or only once the recursion is completely finished?
3. For the base case: Why are we returning an array with only `startNum` as the "base condition" ?  Wouldn't this overwrite the `numbers` variable upon returning?  I'm not sure how the base case works exactly.  It seems to always return something that isn't what we are looking for, yet it controls when the function should stop executing (at the first start of the function call, and/or for ending it).

Comment: There's no closure. In the recursion, you dig all the way down to the base case, then add on to the array all the way back up. This would all be very comprehensible for you if you just added some calls to `console.log` in some key spots in the functions.

Comment: @JaredSmith I thought so as well, but I think it's a bit more involved than just adding console.logs as it wasn't very clear what order things were happening in.  Perhaps I didn't go far enough?  If you disagree and believe it would be simple please let me know how to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this alteration to your function, the only difference being the logging:

```
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (endNum - startNum === 0) {
    console.log("Reached base case, returning: ");
    console.log([startNum]);
    return [startNum];
  } else {
    var numbers = rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum - 1);
    numbers.push(endNum);
    console.log("Returning " + numbers.join(','));
    return numbers;
  }
}
```

And then we call it like this:

```
rangeOfNumbers(0, 7);
```

And it will log

```
Reached base case, returning: 
VM60:4 [0]
VM60:9 Returning 0,1
VM60:9 Returning 0,1,2
VM60:9 Returning 0,1,2,3
VM60:9 Returning 0,1,2,3,4
VM60:9 Returning 0,1,2,3,4,5
VM60:9 Returning 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
VM60:9 Returning 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

So there's no closure. In the recursion, you dig all the way down to the base case, then add on to the array all the way back up.

Comment: Why does it reach the base case first, before returning?  I would've thought everything would happen the other way around...  since the function pushes the endNum to the end of the array every time the function is called.

Comment: @gogogadgetinternet because it recurses: it calls itself before returning. So it gets called with 0 and 7, then it calls itself again with 0 and 6 (*before* returning) then *that* invocation calls itself with 0 and 5, and so on. Nothing actually returns until you hit the base case, then it walks all the way back up the call stack adding each successive return to the array.

Comment: I get it now!!!  Thank you so much.  I don't know why I was having such a hard time seeing what was going on.  I feel like I have a much better understanding.  It drills down all the way to the base case, THEN it starts pushing `numbers.push(endNum)` and it does this each time going backwards up the call stack until it doesn't have anything left to do.  I was thinking that it would just continue until it reached the base case and everything happened before that.  thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: @gogogadgetinternet no problem. Don't feel bad, it's not very easy to understand until you actually trace through each step of the execution (the logging is helpful to that end). Please accept this answer if it works for you. Also note of caution: because it digs all the way down to the base case before anything returns you can overflow the stack if you go too deep: calling `rangeOfNumbers(0, x)` for large values of x will throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this create a closure around numbers?

No, the `numbers` variable name is only referenceable while inside a single block (well, function), and it ends, nothing else has a reference to it. Nothing has saved a reference to it, so it's not a closure.

> Does the function rangeOfNumbers return numbers every single time, or only once the recursion is completely finished?

In each recursive case, the `numbers` variable is returned. In the base case, a new array is returned. But since in recursive cases, the `numbers` variable is a reference to the array returned by the recursive call, the array returned up the chain each time is the same array.

> For the base case: Why are we returning an array with only startNum as the "base condition" ? Wouldn't this overwrite the numbers variable upon returning?

In the base case, there is no `numbers` variable (unless you consider the hoisted variable name which never gets referenced). The array that gets returned *becomes* the `numbers` variable in the recursive calls, but in the base case itself, it's not the `numbers` variable.

Keep in mind that each call of a function results in separate bindings for its variables. For example, with

```
function fn(count) {
  const num = Math.random();
  return num + (count > 1 ? fn(count - 1) : 0);
}
```

Each call of `fn` has a separate `num` variable, which is a random number. The recursive call doesn't overwrite anything from prior calls.

For your `rangeOfNumbers`, the final recursive call results in the base case: the `[startNum]` array. This is returned to the recursive caller and gets stored into the `numbers` variable *for that particular caller* in

```
var numbers = rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum - 1);
```

Then, that one caller adds an item to the array and returns it to *its* caller, and the process repeats until the recursive call stack is completely unwound.

Comment: What if we assign the function call to a variable when we call it initially, e.g.  let myRecursiveArray = rangeOfNumbers(0, 7);  --> would the base case overwrite it then?

Comment: No, the whole `rangeOfNumbers` call stack will resolve before the variable gets assigned to, and whether its result is assigned to a variable or not has no effect on the internals of the recursive function. In this code, nothing gets overwritten anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can write your `range` function by increasing `start` -

```js
const range = (start, end) =>
  start > end                             // terminating condition
    ? []                                  // base case
    : [ start, ...range(start + 1, end) ] // recursive step
    
console.log(range(5,10))
// [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

And another way we can write `range` by decreasing `end` -

```js
const range = (start, end) =>
  end < start                             // terminating condition
    ? []                                  // base case
    : [ ...range(start, end - 1), end ]   // recursive step
    
console.log(range(5,10))
// [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

Notice the similarities and differences in each program